# make multiple vectors based on subset

Tags: r, loops, vector, dataframe, subset

i would like to repeat the following code, whereby the number 1 is replaced by the numbers 1:32

```
test1<-subset.data.frame(df, df$thiessen.Subbasin==1)
v1<-c(test1$thiessen.Percentage)
```

in the end this would generate 32 vectors.
I could copy paste the upper formula 32 times and replace it by the numbers 1 to 32, but there must be a less cumbersome way. Does anyone have an idea, how I could loop this?

Comment: Use `split` i.e. `split(df$thiessen.Percentage, df$thiessen.Subbasin)`

Comment: Where does 32 come from? Is it the distinct values in *Subbasin*?

Comment: yes it is.
So the column      df$thiessen.Subbasin is build up out of 32 rows (excluding the header) containing the numbers 1 to 32.

Comment: So then, will vectors contain only one value? Why not one vector of 32 values?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question, but it would seem the simplest thing to do is just to use a for loop, as follows:

```
ans <- replicate(32, NA)
for (i in 1:32){
test1<-subset.data.frame(df, df$thiessen.Subbasin==i)
ans[i]<-test1$thiessen.Percentage
}
```